# How to log MULTIPLE exceptions to console?

Tags: javascript, exception

I made TWO reference errors in Javascript, try-catch only managed to catch one error.
How to catch all exceptions (errors) inside the code block `try`?

```
    try {
      let x = y + 5; // ReferenceError: y is not defined
      nonexistfunc(); //ReferenceError: nonexistfunc is not defined
    } 

    catch(error){
        let errorArr= [];
        errorArr.push(error);
        console.log(errorArr);    // Output: ReferenceError: y is not defined
    }
```

Comment: "*I made TWO reference errors in Javascript*" - no. While you may have two mistakes, the JS code executes only until the first exception is thrown, `nonexistfunc();` is never evaluated and does not throw a second exception.

Answer (score 5):

Your code *doesn't* cause two errors, because as soon as the first one occurs (`y` is not defined), the `try` block's execution is terminated and control passes to the `catch` block. The `nonexistfunc()` statement is never attempted. Since there's no attempt to reference `nonexistfunc`, there's no error doing so. There aren't two errors to log, just one.

If you wanted to cause, and catch, two errors, you'd need two blocks:

```
let errorArr = [];

try {
    let x = y + 5; // ReferenceError: y is not defined
} catch (error) {
    errorArr.push(error);
}

try {
    nonexistfunc(); // ReferenceError: nonexistfunc is not defined
} catch (error) {
    errorArr.push(error);
}

if (errorArr.length) {
    console.log(errorArr);
}
```

That said, wrapping everything in `try`/`catch` blocks like that is generally not what you want to do. But in this specific case, if you really wanted to get both errors, you'd have to do that so that the first error doesn't prevent the code causing the second from running.

---

I've heard mention of people considering proposing a feature for JavaScript that has the bizarre-sounding name *algebraic effects*, one aspect of which would be that code in a `catch` block (or some new version of one) would be able to continue the code in the `try` block, presumably after having taken some kind of corrective action regarding the error. (Visual Basic [including VB.Net] has this in its all-but-deprecated `On Error Goto ___` and `Resume` statements.) But I don't think that talk has made it into an actual proposal (at least, I don't see it on [the lists](https://github.com/tc39/proposals)).

Comment: Really appreciate your effort for the solution. Is there any method to track all the exceptions without terminate execution after 1st error inside the `try` block? I literally tried the method before you posted after intensively searching on try-catch application based on developer mozilla websites.

Comment: @LuciferRules - No, there isn't, because again: only **one** error occurred! The second thing, that would have been an error, isn't an error because it was never attempted.

Answer (score -1):

T.J. Crowder explained your issue very well. You can also wrap the `try catch` in a helper function.

```js
const catchError = (func) => {
  try {
    func();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

catchError(() => {
  let x = y + 5; // ReferenceError: y is not defined
});

catchError(() => {
  nonexistfunc(); // ReferenceError: nonexistfunc is not defined
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `Promise`. However, this approach is not the best use case here. `Promise.allSettled` takes the array of promises and return new promise when all promises are done or rejected:

```js
Promise.allSettled([
  new Promise(() => {
    let x = y + 5; // ReferenceError: y is not defined
  }),
  new Promise(() => {
    nonexistfunc(); // ReferenceError: nonexistfunc is not defined
  })
]).then((results) => {
    const errors = results.filter(result => result.status === 'rejected');
    errors.forEach((error) => console.error(error.reason));
  })
```

Comment: This is not a use case for promises; doing so is highly misleading. The only asynchronous aspect of the code in this answer is the call to the `then` callback; `new Promise` calls its callback synchronously. This is fundamentally just the two blocks that I've shown in my answer, just using the `Promise` constructor callback as the `try` and `allSettled` to do the `catch`. If you really wanted to do it with functions, it would be better with an explicit function rather than using an asynchronous mechanism for something that isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Yes i agree that is using `Promise` here is a hacky solution, i just wanted to add something different. I edited my answer and added a helper function for catching errors. However, i keep also `Promise` for the future visitors.